# Can't install Quartus II 13.0 SP1 on RedHat 6

Tags: macos, redhat, parallels, quartus

I'm newly Redhat user,

I would like to install Quartus II version 13.0 Sp 1
**"I must install 32-bit compatibility libraries before installing the Quartus II software"**
And I try to use **"apt-get install ia32-libs.i386"** and **"yum install ia32-libs.i386"** are not work.

Can anyone help me to solve this problem?

*** Remark : My Redhat 6 run on Parallels Desktop(Macbook Air 2014)**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On Redhat you should consider using `rpm` instead of `apt-get` or `yum`.
The packages to install are listed in the [altera support site](http://www.altera.com/support/kdb/solutions/rd06142012_65.html):

glibc.i686, libXext.i386, libX11.i386, libXau.i386, libXdmcp.i386, freetype.i386, fontconfig.i386, and expat.i386.